# How can I use –X:Frames in Ironpython?

Tags: c#, command-line, ironpython, frames, interactive

Visual Studio 2010 + Ironpython for .net4

I want to use numpy in ironpython, and they said I must use  frames support.
So, I should running ipy with -X:Frames or -X:FullFrames on the command line.

But, I have two questions:
1.how can i use -X:Frames or -X:FullFrames in  Ironpython Interactive console?

2.If I use C# 4 to load py which contained numpy, how can I use extern parameter like -X:Frames or -X:FullFrames?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Side note: totally surprising to me that numpy requires frames support. What part of adding some numbers requires walking the stack? The only libraries I can think of that have a good reason for *requiring* frames support are ones implementing dynamic scope by walking and mutating stack frames, and similarly "if I can't inspect stack frames I literally have no way to implement this feature" kinds of libraries. Numpy should really do graceful degradation / progressive enhancement (c.f. Transcrypt's port of numpy, which is a Python without frames support.)

Answer (score 6):

1. IronPython Tools for Visual Studio has been deprecated by Python Tools for Visual Studio (see http://pytools.codeplex.com).  Using Python Tools in VS 2010:  open Tools=>Options=>Python Tools=>Interpreter Options and add "-X:FullFrames" to the "Interactive Window Options" field.
2. When you create your IronPython engine via **IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine**, use the overload that accepts a **Dictionary**.  This dictionary parameter needs a *FullFrames* key set to *true*.  [Performance of Mass-Evaluating Expressions in IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379040/performance-of-mass-evaluating-expressions-in-ironpython) will give you a good idea how to do this.