# Is there a way to assign Python options inside the script?

Tags: python, ironpython

For IronPython to import some modules it requires `-X:Frames` option to be passed. (`ipy -X:Frames`)

However, when using Visual Studio we can only assign this option if we use interactive window. To execute a Python file there is no way that I know to pass parameters. Maybe something like:

```
some_name.options.append("X:Frames")
import my_module
```

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078039/how-can-i-use-xframes-in-ironpython) is still relevant?

Comment: I am already doing that when hosting IronPython or running it from command line. Now, I am debugging it and not using interactive console.

Comment: I don't suspect this option can be changed once the interpreter is running. Why can't you use project properties/debug/interpreter arguments when launching in visual studio?

Comment: @SimonOpelt Now I am doing it. I was just trying to use IronPython's global interpreter to launch the code. Do you think should I delete the question?