# Pip in Visual Studio not installing packages

Tags: visual-studio, pip, ironpython

Whenever I try to install a package ('theano', in this case) it gives me this:

```
----- Installing 'theano' -----
Unhandled exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\runpy.py", line 170, in run_module
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\runpy.py", line 101, in _get_module_details
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\pkgutil.py", line 456, in get_loader
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\pkgutil.py", line 466, in find_loader
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\pkgutil.py", line 422, in iter_importers
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\six.py", line 701, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\six.py", line 692, in exec_
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_getframe'
----- Failed to install 'theano' -----
```

Sorry, I'm not sure what else to say or do. Note that this happens with other packages, too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `-X:FullFrames` attribute, which will not be set when `Visual Studio` executed the commands for installing packages. Take a look at this SO answer [How can I use –X:Frames in Ironpython?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6128672/2630261).

This important part is:

> IronPython Tools for Visual Studio has been deprecated by Python Tools for Visual Studio (see http://pytools.codeplex.com). Using Python Tools in VS 2010: > open Tools=>Options=>Python Tools=>Interpreter Options and add "-X:FullFrames" to the "Interactive Window Options" field.